# why am i getting redirecting to wrong view in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to render to different page using URLs in django,I have written all codes as the tutorials as well,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index,name="index"),
    path('', views.register,name="register"),
    path('', views.login,name="login")
]


def index(request):
    print("hello index")
    return render(request,'index.html')

def register(request):
    return render(request,'register.html')
  
def login(request):
    print("hello login")
    return render(request,'login.html')
```

but, whenever I hit that register link on my HTML it just always takes me to index.html.

```
<ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}"> Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'register' %}"> Register</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}"> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
```

I have also tried putting something in the routes

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('index', views.index,name="index"),
        path('register', views.register,name="register"),
        path('login', views.login,name="login")
    ]
```

but this time it gives errors like **The empty path didn’t match any of these.**

I have worked on different django project using the above pattern and it was working perfectly fine.Where am I making it wrong? Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: every url has the same path, the solution is your last attempt but then you need to call the url accordingly i.e `localhost:8000/index`

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same path name for different views. You need to use a different path for each view.

for Example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index,name="index"),
    path('register/', views.register,name="register"),
    path('login/', views.login,name="login")
]


def index(request):
    print("hello index")
    return render(request,'index.html')

def register(request):
    return render(request,'register.html')
  
def login(request):
    print("hello login")
    return render(request,'login.html')
```